# ADODB Connection Fails on Windows 7 but Not XP

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, ado, windows-7-x64

I have a simple program to test opening a connection to excel file using ADODB.
This is ASP Classic using VBScript.
Here is the code:

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<% Response.buffer = true %>
<html>
<body>
<%

'Name of the excel file
exceldb="AW_Test.xls"
excel_file_name=Server.MapPath(exceldb)
response.write(excel_file_name)

Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)}; DriverId=790; DBQ=" &excel_file_name & ";"

cn.Close
Set cn=Nothing

Response.Write("All is good in the world...")

%>
</body>
</html>
```

When trying to run on this configuration:

- Windows 7 64bit
- IIS 7
- Application Pool in 32 bit mode
- Files in root directory
- Running on Local Host [http://localhost/adotest.asp]

I get the following results:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AW_Test.xls 

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' 

[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '(unknown)'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data. 

/adotest2.asp, line 13
```

However, on the same machine under this configuration:

- Virtual PC in XP Mode
- IIS 6
- Files in root directory
- Running on Local Host [http://localhost/adotest.asp]

I get the following results:

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\AW_Test.xls
All is good in the world...
```

Things I have verified/tried:

- Verified permissions (note this is the root directory)
- Tried using the Jet Engine instead with

  ```
     cn.Open 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\AW_Test.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=No"'
  ```

Got error:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AW_Test.xls
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' 

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified 

/adotest3.asp, line 13
```

- Verified ALL application pools running in 32 bit mode
- Verified drivers exist in SYSWOW side of data sources

I am sure I am missing something simple but, I am about out of things to try.
I know there are much better ways than ASP Classic etc. but, this should still work...

I appreciate any help...

Comment: please check the accepted answer in this: http://forums.iis.net/t/1174099.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try with just:

```
cn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)}; DBQ=" &excel_file_name & ";"
```

It should work..